# Go How can I use JavaScript code on my html page

Tags: go

Problem: I have **script src** tag in my index.html page but on browser this script doesn't load ( actually it loads but looks like index.html file 0_0 see pictures below ). The question is: How can I use JavaScript code which is in different file ( myscripts.js ) on my html page ?

[js file looks like html ( index.html ) file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol9kU.jpg)

During googling I found "solution" but I does not work completely like it should. I just added this line to viewHandler method :

```
http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
```

After this, project started look like this:

[index.html after adding line above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRRmi.jpg)

**To sum up:**

My goal is to show html page and use javascript function which are in scripts/ folder.

**Project Structure :**

```
-scripts 
 --myscripts.js
-templates
 --index.html
server.go
```

**Server.go :**

```
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("listening . . .")
            tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
        }

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", viewHandler)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**myscripts.js:**

```
function clickFunc(){
console.log("clicked")
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myscripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="clickFunc()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: rofl, "http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])"  - Memories in, as an example of idiotic code. Small you mess in head, definitely. Example my code: https://github.com/spouk/spoukfw/blob/master/spoukrender.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to serve static files from a specific directory using the [`http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) package.

For example:

```
func main() {
  ScriptsDirectory := http.FileServer(http.Dir("scripts"))
  http.Handle("/scripts", ScriptsDirectory)

  log.Println("Listening at port 3000")
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Will let you server the file directly from that directory.

From there you can reference the `/scripts` directory in your **index.html** page as is.

[Here](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/serving-static-sites-with-go) is also a tutorial where this technique is used.

Comment: +1 to this and never use r.URL.Path[1:] as the question did - you're allowing user input to directly choose a path on the filesystem.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that StaticFiles should be replaced with ScriptsDirectory ? 
So I can either use Templates and show html pages with javascript inside like: 

`<script> alert('hello'); </script>`

OR I can use FileServer to provide files but not a templates ? 
Can I somehow use both ? Like templates for html and fileserver for only one directory "scripts" ?

Comment: @Illia thanks for the catch. Edited. Golang provides its own tempting engine which you can read about [here](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)